# Best Searching algorithms to find a word from millions of words in Java

Tags: java, search, java-8, hashmap, hashset

Recently, in an interview I was asked **which data structure/library would you use, to search a particular word from among multi-million of words**.

I said, HashSet, as its executes the search operation, on average, in almost a constant-time. I also mentioned that we should **initialize it with double the known number of elements**, so that I will have lesser hash collision as the load would get divided among larger number of buckets and the individual linked list would be of half the size (would it really enhance the performance?). But then again, the interviewer asked me if that would suffice and was expecting something more.

What else can we do to achieve a higher level of search optimization or any other data structure/library that can help increase the efficiency?

Comment: He might have been hinting at a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) for better memory optimization (millions of words tend to have _a lot_ of overlapping characters :) ).

Comment: You *could* check the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure

Comment: it felt he wanted some modification in the way we initialize the hashset

Comment: If it was meant a fulltext search you could have used Apache Lucene.